# (iOS Swift)Google Maps animateWithCameraUpdate not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am working with Google maps in iOS. I wanted to animate my Camera such that it shows all the required Lat, Lngs. I am storing those locations in the array(as CLLocationCoordinate2D instances) and using GMSCoordinateBounds class to add these locations. This is my code:

```
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        bounds.includingCoordinate(firstLocation)
        bounds.includingCoordinate(lastLocation)
        let camUpdate = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 60)

        mMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: firstLocation.latitude, longitude: firstLocation.longitude, zoom: 18)

        mMapView.animate(with: camUpdate)
```

firstLocation and lastLocation have correct values but the camera is not animating. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Very silly mistake. includingCoordinates function returns GMSCoordinateBounds object. I had to set to itself again for it to work like so:

```
bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(firstLocation)

bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(lastLocation)
```

If i set like above, it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me lot of times, i had the same issue :)